# How to draw lines on UIImage with swift ?

Tags: swift, ios-app-group

I am new to swift. I have followed many tutorial to learn it. Can someone guide me how to draw lines with UIImage ? I want to draw some lines on image .

If I draw image on UIView in on draw method - will the performance will be same as image on UIImage- do I still able to get full resolution and pinch zoom etc features.

Comment: You should take a look at CoreGraphics.

Comment: @VatsalManot thanks for your input . I will definitely look into that . By the way can you suggest some tutorial link ?

Comment: I've submitted an answer. Please accept it if you find it useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[iOS Drawing Concepts](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/2DDrawing/Conceptual/DrawingPrintingiOS/GraphicsDrawingOverview/GraphicsDrawingOverview.html) from the iOS documentation library should serve as a useful guide.